# Distinguishing first launch on UI Tests

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, fastlane-snapshot

I want to use **Fastlane Snapshot** in order to generate screenshots for my app. But the behavior of the app is different when launch for the first time and launching after that. 
How do I manage to get a consistent behavior in order to grab the screenshots?
(this question is also relevant for any UI test desired consistency I presume)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `UserDefaults` class to preserve data in your app so that you can stub data in your tests.

If we assume that the Bool key you use to see if it's the first launch is `isFirstTime`, in order to stub it in your UI test, you should pass it to `launchArguments` following the value `YES` or `NO` (for Bool values). Note that I added `-` sign before key, this is the way it works:

```
class FirstTimeLaunchTest: XCTestCase {

    let app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false

        app.launchArguments += ["-isFirstTime", "YES"]
        app.launch()
    }

    func testWelcomeScreenShown() {
        XCTAssert(app.navigationBars["Welcome"].exists)
    }
}
```

For tests where you'd like to have first start skipped, use this class:

```
class LaterLaunchesTest: XCTestCase {

    let app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false

        app.launchArguments += ["-isFirstTime", "NO"]
        app.launch()
    }

    func testMainAppScreenShown() {
        XCTAssert(app.navigationBars["My App"].exists)
    }
}
```

One **note** though: If you are using [SwiftyUserDefaults](https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults) library, this solution wouldn't work. There is a problem in the current version of the library where converting `YES` and `NO` strings to `true` and `false` is not working as expected. There was a [PR](https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults/pull/149) that solved this problem (that is rejected), but to solve this problem, you can look at the solutions #2 and #3 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223139/1253279).

Comment: What determines if it is first launch or not is not necessarily a launch argument, rather if the app was already installed on the simulator. For example I have a "Location Permission" alert which will pop up and needs to be interacted with. If I understand correctly I would have to simulate the app "not running for the first time" when it actually DOES.

Comment: There is no way to know if your app is installed on the simulator before. Also, your question is not good since you haven't described what are the differences when running the app for the first and for every next time. But, from your comment, since you ask for location when user starts the app for the first time, there is no way to simulate showing system dialog more than once, as far as I know. I have tried to find solution for that, but no luck. If you want you can try these two tests if you use `UserDefaults`. Adding `launchArguments` to app is a way to stub `UserDefaults` data in UI tests.